# One to many Mongo strategy with query on both collections

Tags: mongodb, database-design, nosql

I've got two collections: one with ~7.600.000 documents containing information about available trips and one with ~5000 documents containing information about hotels with region, city and country data. The trips collection has field with id of certain hotel.

my problem is, that I have to query both collections to get information about certain trip: location information from hotels collection and other information like price, number of people etc from trips collection.

I've read about mapreduce strategy of merging two collections, but i think that it won't fit in my case because it'll create only 5000 documents if I link them using hotel id? Is it possible?

Another approach is two embed hotels information in trip collection, but I'm afraid of updating hotel information in this case.

Please give me some advice, and tell which approach will be the best?

Comment: look at: look at: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references

this is a not solution, just way...

Comment: so you suggest doing two queries?

Comment: Since a trip likely won't contain lots of these connections, test the performance of a query from the client to the DB. How long does it take on average? Is it acceptable to your users? I think they should distinct documents. You might even consider adding a timed cache on the client with your smaller set of data to avoid some unnecessary calls for data that may not change frequently.

Answer (score 0):

You have many options. It's all about deciding where to "join" the data. The options:

1. Join on the front end. Maybe bring back all trips first and then use AJAX calls to lazily load the hotel information. (Assuming a web application). Point being, two calls might not be the worst thing!
2. Use map/reduce in Mongo to output the data as you want it. It won't work in real time, but it will give you the right results. It wouldn't be limited to 5,000 documents. You could start with the bigger trip collection and bring in what you need. It's very flexible.
3. Embed the hotel information. As a note, you only want to embed hotel information if it's not changing all that often. If it changes constantly, I would consider leaving things as is.

For a lot of the work I do with Mongo, I've found that two calls isn't so bad - especially when dealing with fast changing data.